# How to store values of check boxes in another table

Tags: php, mysql

I had hobby_id in the same table hobbies.
But i need to store all the hobby_id whichever is selected check box in another table. Please provide the coding for this. I really don't have any idea. The given coding is to retrieve the value from mysql and display it in check box.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM hobbies";
$result = mysqli_query($con, "$query");
while ($r=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $hobby=$r["hobby_name"];?>
    <label><input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='$hobby'><?php echo $hobby;?></label>
}
```

Comment: Where is total form ?

Comment: too broad. how do you want to store them? as comma seprated list (not good), as separated row for each checkbox? join conditions - user related, hobby related? what is the stucture and purpose of the another table?

Comment: I need to store as comma separated list.

Comment: again too broad. however, after submit (hopefully POST), you can use `$checkList = implode($_POST['check'])` in order to get them as comma separated list list and to proceed with DB stuffs.

Answer (score 0):

Add your "input"  tags under "form"  tag. submit that form and you will get all checked ids in to "check"  variable. then you can save in to another table.

Comment: I had already have form tag. Under the form tag only it has input tag. But when i post it wont provide any result.